# Good approach with MongoDB, comparing two fields to determine if value exists in both?

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

**example:**

- _id = 001

  - field 'location' = PARIS FRANCE
  - field 'country' = FRANCE
- _id = 002

  - field 'location' = TORONTO
  - field 'country' = CANADA

**desired result:**

ability to recognize that for _id 001, "france" is also in the value for ***location*** field;

whereas, _id 002 does not have a value from ***country*** that also is in ***location***

Instead of relying on pandas, would like to see if there are more efficient options using pymongo, for example?

Comment: How would you differentiate when the country's name is also part of the city's name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sensitive to case, and possible abbreviations, etc., but here's one way to identify if one string is contained within the other.

Given an example collection like this:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "001",
    "location": "PARIS FRANCE",
    "country": "FRANCE"
  },
  {
    "_id": "002",
    "location": "TORONTO",
    "country": "CANADA"
  }
]
```

This will set `"isIn"` if `"country"` is contained within `"location"` or vice-versa.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "isIn": {
        "$gte": [
          {
            "$sum": [
              { // returns pos or -1 if not found
                "$indexOfCP": ["$location", "$country"]
              },
              {"$indexOfCP": ["$country", "$location"]}
            ]
          },
          -1
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example output:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "001",
    "country": "FRANCE",
    "isIn": true,
    "location": "PARIS FRANCE"
  },
  {
    "_id": "002",
    "country": "CANADA",
    "isIn": false,
    "location": "TORONTO"
  }
]
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/w-vVdspDlAN).